# Similar methods with different parameters types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript methods:

```
authorize(permission: string, id?: number) : Observable<boolean> {

  return this.authorize(Permission[permission], id);

}

authorize(permission: Permission, id?: number) : Observable<boolean> {
  // authorization code
}
```

The first receives a permission of String type and converts it to Permission enum type.

Then calls the second method that accepts a permission of enum Permission type.

But I get the error:

```
Duplicate function implementation.
```

It seems Typescript is ignoring the parameters types.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's static type system including such type annotations is [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when compiled to JavaScript, which is what actually runs. So what you're proposing would end up compiling to something like (assuming ES2017)

```
class Thingy {
    authorize(permission, id) {
        return this.authorize(Permission[permission], id);
    }
    authorize(permission, id) {
        // authorization code
    }
}
```

In JavaScript, you can't have two methods with the same name... well, you *can*, but only the second one will ever be called.  So this approach won't work.

---

What you need to do is have a single method whose implementation can handle both ways of calling it.  TypeScript lets you represent different call signatures as [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), but you still have to have a single implementation that does the work.

In your example, though, overloads are unneccessary, since you can represent the combination of both signatures as a single signature whose `permission` parameter is a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `string` and `Permission`.  And while I don't know what a `Permission` is (this is why [minimum reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are useful), as long as it's not a type alias for `string` you can make a branching implementation that behaves the way you want:

```
authorize(permission: string | Permission, id?: number): Observable<boolean> {
  if (typeof permission === "string") {
  return this.authorize(Permission[permission], id);
} else {
  // authorization code
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!